# How do I see all instances managed by Autofac?

Tags: autofac

I am exploring concepts in Autofac, and I want to count all the instances of a given type. How can I do that?

For example, I wire up a simple dependency:

```cs
containerBuilder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>();
```

And then at runtime I want to see how many instances of `IMyService` are currently managed by the DI container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short here, you can't. At least, not out of the box and not easily.

For example, the container manages some things at the root level, but then [lifetime scopes](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html) also have various instances they control that may be disposed when those scopes are disposed. The container doesn't track parent-to-child relationships for scopes, that's on you, so you would be responsible for rectifying that whole set of instances, including all the shared ones (like singletons), etc.

Probably the easiest way to do some sort of inventory would be a memory profiler, where you could query by object/interface type and then determine what's holding a reference to it.

You could also potentially write something [using the diagnostics support](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting/diagnostics.html) to keep a rough set of statistics for things, but it'd be on you to figure out the right set of stuff to track.

For reference, I don't know of any DI container that lets you enumerate all of the instances of a given type that are somehow under management by the container. It's not just that Autofac doesn't support it, it's that most don't and it's not a feature folks request. I think if someone did request it for Autofac we'd probably turn it down due to the memory overhead and complexity required in trying to offer such a thing. Lots of downside, very little upside.